# How to sum dynamic value produced by jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi guys i am totally new here actually i am about to fix the problem and was able to get (almost) the solution from here

[How to sum Jquery Outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659119/how-to-sum-jquery-outputs)

i got all the idea the problem is i cant output the total sad that i am really noob when it comes to jquery

What i want to do is sum up all so i can have the total bill here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('input:radio[name="meal"]').change(function(ev){
        
  if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {     
   var meal = 20;
  }
        else {            
   var meal = 30;
        } 
  
        $('#meal').html((meal).toFixed(2));

    }); 

 $('input:radio[name="drinks"]').change(function(ev){
 
  if ($(this).val() == 'Ice Tea') {
            var drinks = 1;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Coke') {
            var drinks = 1.20;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Lemonade') {
            var drinks = 2;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Water') {
            var drinks = 1.75;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot choco') {
            var drinks = 3;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot coffee') {
            var drinks = 1.25;
        }
        else {
             var drinks = 0;
        }
  
  $('#drinks').html((drinks).toFixed(2));
 }); 


 $('input:radio[name="extras"]').change(function(ev){
  
  if ($(this).val() == 'Rice') {
            var extras = 10;
        }
  else if ($(this).val() == 'Gravy') {
            var extras = 5;
        }
        else {
             var extras = 0;
        }
  $('#extras').html((extras).toFixed(2));
 });
 
  $('textarea[name="spoon"]').keyup(function(ev){
     
 var spoon = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
 var spoon = spoon*2;
 $("#spoon").html(spoon); 
    
 });

$('input:text[name="fork"]').keyup(function(ev){
     
 var fork = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
 var fork = fork*1.25;
 $("#fork").html(fork);        
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Calculator base on radio buttons</h1>
<h2>Question 1: Meal</h2>
<div>
<label class="radio"><input name="meal" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>Burger with fries</label>
</div>
<div>
<label class="radio"><input name="meal" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />Chicken with rice</label>
</div>

<h2>Question 2: Drinks</h2>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Ice Tea" /> Ice Tea
<input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Coke" /> Coke
<input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Lemonade" /> Lemonade
<input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Water" /> Water
<input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Hot choco" /> Hot choco
<input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Hot coffee" /> Hot coffee
<input type="radio" name="drinks" value="No drinks" /> No drinks
</div>

<h2>Question 3: Extras</h2>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="extras" value="Rice" /> Rice
<input type="radio" name="extras" value="Gravy" /> Gravy
<input type="radio" name="extras" value="No Extra" /> No Extra
</div>

<h2>Question 4: How many extra spoon?</h2>
<div>
<textarea name="spoon" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<h2>Question 5: How many extra fork?</h2>
<div>
<input name="fork" type="text" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>

<hr />
<div>
<b>Meal:</b> <span id="meal"></span>
<div></div>
<b>Drinks:</b> <span id="drinks"></span>
<div></div>
<b>Extras:</b> <span id="extras"></span>
<div></div>
<b>Spoon:</b> <span id="spoon"></span>
<div></div>
<b>Fork:</b> <span id="fork"></span>
</div>

<div>
 <h3>
 <b>Total:</b><span id="total"></span>
 </h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you change the html structure - ie can you add data attributes to the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead to use:

```
$('#drinks').html('string')
```

in order to change the span text you can use

```
$('#drinks').text('string')
```

Whenever you change the value of the span (i.e.: Meal, Drinks...) you can trigger a change event so that it can be handled. An example is:

```
$("#fork").text(fork).trigger('change');
```

Now, you can create a change handler where you can update the total. 
It's possible to compute the total using the javascript function [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
$('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').on('change', function(e) {
    var total = $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork')
                           .toArray().reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc + +val.textContent   ;
    }, 0);
    $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
})
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input:radio[name="meal"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {
            var meal = 20;
        }
        else {
            var meal = 30;
        }

        $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:radio[name="drinks"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Ice Tea') {
            var drinks = 1;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Coke') {
            var drinks = 1.20;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Lemonade') {
            var drinks = 2;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Water') {
            var drinks = 1.75;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot choco') {
            var drinks = 3;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot coffee') {
            var drinks = 1.25;
        }
        else {
            var drinks = 0;
        }

        $('#drinks').text((drinks).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });


    $('input:radio[name="extras"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Rice') {
            var extras = 10;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Gravy') {
            var extras = 5;
        }
        else {
            var extras = 0;
        }
        $('#extras').text((extras).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });

    $('textarea[name="spoon"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var spoon = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        $("#spoon").text(spoon).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:text[name="fork"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var fork = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        $("#fork").text(fork).trigger('change');
    });



    $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').on('change', function(e) {
        var total = $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').toArray().reduce(function(acc, val) {
            return acc + +val.textContent   ;
        }, 0);
        $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>Calculator base on radio buttons</h1>
<h2>Question 1: Meal</h2>
<div>
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>Burger with fries</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />Chicken with rice</label>
</div>

<h2>Question 2: Drinks</h2>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Ice Tea" /> Ice Tea
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Coke" /> Coke
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Lemonade" /> Lemonade
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Water" /> Water
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Hot choco" /> Hot choco
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" value="Hot coffee" /> Hot coffee
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" value="No drinks" /> No drinks
</div>

<h2>Question 3: Extras</h2>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="extras" value="Rice" /> Rice
    <input type="radio" name="extras" value="Gravy" /> Gravy
    <input type="radio" name="extras" value="No Extra" /> No Extra
</div>

<h2>Question 4: How many extra spoon?</h2>
<div>
    <textarea name="spoon" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<h2>Question 5: How many extra fork?</h2>
<div>
    <input name="fork" type="text" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>

<hr />
<div>
    <b>Meal:</b> <span id="meal"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>Drinks:</b> <span id="drinks"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>Extras:</b> <span id="extras"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>Spoon:</b> <span id="spoon"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>Fork:</b> <span id="fork"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>
        <b>Total:</b><span id="total"></span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great its just a part of a larger script but i'd definitely be back.. thank you for your input..

Answer (score 0):

You can name the individual items amount with a class name says "itemAmount" and then use jquery .each function to select the individual Amount and add those to get the total amount.

See the modification i have made to your code the modifications are marked in bold. I have added a function to check if a text is numeric isNumeric and updateTotal() to add the items and update the total.

use this jsfiddle url if you want to see it in action   https://jsfiddle.net/princedc/wnsa61g8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('input:radio[name="meal"]').change(function(ev){

            if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {     
                var meal = 20;
            }
            else {            
                var meal = 30;
            }   

            $('#meal').html((meal).toFixed(2));
            updateTotal();
        });

function updateTotal(){
    var totalAmount = 0.0;
        $('.itemAmount').each(function() {
           if(isNumeric($(this).text())){
                totalAmount = totalAmount + parseFloat($(this).text());
                $('#total').text(totalAmount.toFixed(2));
           }

        });
}

    function isNumeric(n) {
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

        $('input:radio[name="drinks"]').change(function(ev){

            if ($(this).val() == 'Ice Tea') {
                var drinks = 1;
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == 'Coke') {
                var drinks = 1.20;
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == 'Lemonade') {
                var drinks = 2;
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == 'Water') {
                var drinks = 1.75;
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot choco') {
                var drinks = 3;
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot coffee') {
                var drinks = 1.25;
            }
            else {
                 var drinks = 0;
            }

            $('#drinks').html((drinks).toFixed(2));
            updateTotal();
        }); 


        $('input:radio[name="extras"]').change(function(ev){

            if ($(this).val() == 'Rice') {
                var extras = 10;
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == 'Gravy') {
                var extras = 5;
            }
            else {
                 var extras = 0;
            }
            $('#extras').html((extras).toFixed(2));
        updateTotal();
        });

            $('textarea[name="spoon"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var spoon = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        var spoon = spoon*2;
        $("#spoon").html(spoon);    
        updateTotal();
        });

    $('input:text[name="fork"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var fork = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        var fork = fork*1.25;
        $("#fork").html(fork);      
      **updateTotal();**
        });

    });
```

Comment: i really like the idea but i think i'll stick with the other solution thanks :)